# Kernel panic - possible due to IR reciever?

Tags: kernel, 13.10

I use Ubuntu 13.10 (freshly installed as 13.04 and later upgraded) on my media center - a Asrock ION 3D. Usually when I boot the computer, I get the result below. After rebooting one or several times, I get a successful boot.

Knowing very little about how stuff is working under the hood of Ubuntu, I guess the problem could be related to the build-in IR reciever:

> RIP [<...>] ir_raw_event_store_with_filter...

I don't care about IR capabilities since I never use the remote. I can't see an option to disable it through BIOS.

**Can I somehow remove the infrared component from Ubuntu?**
or
**Is my problem related to something completely different?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, you can blacklist drivers from loading. If you do get a successful boot, you can use Terminal commands to add the IR driver (`rc_core`) to the blacklist:

1. Change to the configuration folder for *modprobe* (the driver loader).

   `cd /etc/modprobe.d`
2. Switch to a root shell.

   `sudo su`
3. Create a new blacklist file that blacklists the module.

   `echo 'blacklist rc_core' > blacklist-rc-core.conf`

Upon reboot, the blacklist should be in effect and Ubuntu should no longer try to load the offending module.